# Parametrization of a quartic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, parametrization

I know how to find a parametrization of a cubic genus $0$ curve. But I don't know it for quartics and i couldn't find it anywhere. Can you give me an example of a parametrization of a quartic? What are the techniques? Where can I find these techniques?

If you have not, I can give you : $y^2=\frac{t^2(t^2+24)}{3}$

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I want to find a rational parametrization.

Comment: this specific case is not hard, as it is a double cover of the conic $y^2=t(t+24)/24$. Hence you can parametrize the conic and then ask for the $t$-coordinate to be a square.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean $y^2=t(t+24)/3$? I guess there is a little typo there.

Comment: Yes of course, sorry about that!

Comment: @nomadd: Let $v=\frac{y}{t}$, then we get $v^2=\frac{(t^2+24)}{3}$.  
This is a quadratic equation and you can parametrize it.